# dashDB to BigInsights using Data Connect

Tags: ibm-cloud, dataconnect

I use Data Connect to copy data from a dashDB table to BigInsights HDFS but even if the activity completes successfully, I can't find the data in hadoop. Am I missing something? I gave 777 privileges on the target HDFS dir.
Thanks
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX9nm.png)

Comment: I would suggest raising a support ticket.